# Does bing have advanced search operators?

Tags: search-engines, bing

I'm interested in search operators you can type in the search box, not the Advanced Search interface.

- Does bing have search opeartors?
- Where's the documentation for them?

Comment: It would have been well on topic on http://webapps.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Power-Inside In fact, the question has already been asked at http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18847/bing-search-extension-google-like

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found them:

1. Perform a search
2. Click **Advanced** on the results page
3. Click on **Get more search tips**
4. Click on the **Advanced search options** topic
5. Click on the **Advanced search keywords** topic

I don't think you can link to the page directly. Otherwise I would.

These are the search keywords supported (2009/08/06):

- `contains:`
- `filetype:`
- `inanchor:`
- `inbody:`
- `intitle:`
- `ip:`
- `language`
- `loc`
- `location`
- `prefer:`
- `site:`
- `feed:`
- `hasfeed:`
- `url:`

Comment: Hmm, I don't have an "advanced" link.

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: I know you mentioned not the advanced option, but you can type in the operators manually if you want you.  Microsoft just took them and gave them a definition the average person can understand.  This would also apply for google.

You can type in "cars NOT ford" for example and get all cars search terms that do not mention ford.

http://www.bing.com/search?q=dogs&go=&form=QBRE&scope=web&qs=n

If you search for something, it has the number or search results and an "Advanced" button. From there, you can select advanced options and search by search terms, site/domain, coutry/region, or language.

Here is the help:
http://help.live.com/help.aspx?project=wl_searchv1&market=en-US&querytype=keyword&query=redliub&tmt=&domain=www.bing.com:80

These are the search terms options and there relations:

- All of these terms: Uses an AND (A search keyword that you can use to find results that contain all the search terms you specify.) operation. Ignores punctuation and stop words (Words that are frequently used, but that do not offer descriptive value to search engines. For example, a, of, and the are considered stop words.) .
- Any of these terms: Uses an OR (A search keyword that you can use to find results that contain either of the search terms that you specify.) operation. Ignores punctuation and stop words.
- This exact phrase: Searches for the exact phrase, including punctuation and stop words.
- None of these terms: Uses a NOT (A search keyword that you can use to find results that don't contain a search term you specify.) operation. The NOT operation groups the terms within parentheses, including punctuation and stop words.

Answer (score 6):

The full list of available advanced operators can be found at the [Advanced Operator Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff795620.aspx). The current landing isn't helpful, but the operator keywords, listed below, are in the topic tree.

Operator Keywords:

```
altloc:
AND
contains:
define
domain:
ext:
feed:
filetype:
hasfeed:
imagesize:
inanchor:
inbody:
instreamset:
intitle:
ip:
keyword
language:
literalmeta:
loc:
location:
meta:
msite:
near:
NOT
OR
site:
url:
-
&
&&
(
)
:
[
]
|
||
"phrase”
```

Many of these take a string value, but many also use specific values that require checking the MSDN reference.